# GCP cloud function using python for storageBucketPublicAccessRemediationFunction

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am writing a python code in a  GCP cloud function for storage Bucket Public Access Remediation Function.

Here is python code,

import logging
import os
import base64
import json
from googleapiclient import discovery

LOG_LEVEL = os.getenv('LOGLEVEL', 'INFO')
logger = logging.getLogger("CIS-1-0-0-5-1-bucket-public-access-remediation-function")
logger.setLevel(logging.getLevelName(LOG_LEVEL))
logging.getLogger('googleapiclient.discovery_cache').setLevel(logging.ERROR)

PROJECT_ID = os.getenv("GCP_PROJECT")
GCP_REGION = os.getenv('FUNCTION_REGION')

def google_cloud_function_handler(event, context):
"""
Google Cloud function for the use case:
Rule Name: Identities and credentials: Ensure that Cloud Storage bucket is not anonymously or publicly
accessible
Definition: Bucket should not have Policies with [ Members . lAlUsers eq True or Members . AllAuthenticatedUsers
eq True ]
"""
try:
violations = json.loads(base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8'))
for violation in violations.get('violations'):
project_id = violation.get("account_id", PROJECT_ID)
region = violation.get("region_name", GCP_REGION)
bucket_name = violation["resource_id"].split('buckets/')[1]

```
        logger.info(f'Got event with Project ID: {project_id}, Bucket: {bucket_name} and Region: {region}')
        disable_public_access_of_bucket(bucket_name, project_id, region)

except Exception as error:
    raise Exception(f'Error occurred while doing remediation of the use case. Reason: {error}') from error
```

def disable_public_access_of_bucket(bucket_name, project_id, region):
"""
This function disables public access of the bucket by removing principals ('allUsers' and 'allAuthenticatedUsers')
from bucket's permission
:param bucket_name: Name of bucket
:param project_id: Id of the GCP project
:param region: Region of bucket
"""

```
try:
    service = discovery.build('storage', 'v1')
    is_bucket_public = False
    # get IAM policy of the bucket
    policy = service.buckets().getIamPolicy(bucket=bucket_name).execute()
    logger.debug(f'Response from getIamPolicy method: {policy}')
    bindings = policy['bindings']
    for binding in bindings:
        if 'allAuthenticatedUsers' in binding['members']:
            is_bucket_public = True
            binding['members'].remove('allAuthenticatedUsers')
        if 'allUsers' in binding['members']:
            is_bucket_public = True
            binding['members'].remove('allUsers')

    if is_bucket_public:
        # update IAM policy of the bucket
        response = service.buckets().setIamPolicy(bucket=bucket_name, body=policy).execute()
        logger.debug(f'Response from setIamPolicy method: {response}')
        logger.info(f'Successfully completed remediation for Bucket: {bucket_name} of Project: {project_id}')
    else:
        logger.info(f'Remediation was already completed for Bucket: {bucket_name} of Project: {project_id}')

except Exception as error:
    logger.exception(
        f'Error occurred while disabling public access of Bucket: {bucket_name}. Reason: {error}. '
        f'Skipping remediation for this bucket')
```

When I execute this function , I am getting errors like

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app     response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request

TypeError: google_cloud_function_handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WsHg.png)

can someone help me to fix this errors? where exactly I need to change the code ?

when I hit the cloud function URL I am getting this error : 500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: here is the code : https://github.com/netskopeoss/CSPM-GCP-AutoRemediation/blob/134b8871df2d317943cfefb7264ed433e13a04d9/GoogleFunctions/StorageBucketPublicAccessRemediationFunction/google_function_handler.py